# How to run reversed animation with Cocos3D?

Tags: cocos3d

I use below code to run the animation, but how to reversed the animation? (For example, a door  model has an open animation, but I want to make it close)

```
CC3ResourceNode* rezNode = [CC3PODResourceNode nodeFromFile: @"bd1hW1368.POD"];
    [self addChild: rezNode];

    CCActionInterval *stride = [CC3Animate actionWithDuration:10.0];
    [rezNode runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:stride]];
```

**[UPDATE]**

Related to Bill's answer, I create a continuous door close/open animation as below:

```
    CC3ResourceNode* rezNode = [CC3PODResourceNode nodeFromFile: @"bd1hW1368.POD"];
    [self addChild: rezNode];

    CC3Animate *stride = [CC3Animate actionWithDuration:10.0];
    CC3Animate *reversedStride = [CC3Animate actionWithDuration:10.0];
    reversedStride.isReversed = YES;

    CCRepeatForever *repeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCSequence actionWithArray:@[stride, reversedStride]]];
    [rezNode runAction:repeat];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most `CCActionInterval` subclasses, `CC3Animate` supports the `reverse` method, which returns a new `CC3Animate` instance configured to run backwards.

You can also reuse the same `CC3Animate` instance and set the `isReversed` property to `YES`, but creating a separate instance using the `reverse` method will allow you to more easily do things like sequence a door open action followed by a door close action.

Comment: Thanks Bill, it works, I update my question with answer.